# 1998 Chevy Blazer - Headlights not getting power on one side

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, headlight, blazer

Can someone help me out?

I had HID's in my blazer for about 3 months and the passenger side always went out so I took them out and put the regular headlight bulb back in.  After I did that, I now have no power to the brights or low beams, but just on the passenger side.

I checked the fuses and tried changing the headlight sockets tonight and it didn't fix anything.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Headlights are sometimes switched by a relay. Try tracing the wires back and see if you can spot one. If so, it should be easy enough to test -- just try swapping it with the relay for the other side and see if the problem follows the relay. If not, then you should be able to check the input line to see if it has power when you turn the lights on. If not, then you probably have a bad headlight switch. If you check the switch and it's OK then you must have a short, possibly where the switch wire comes through the firewall.

Comment: my buddy tested for power at both headlight sockets, and it had none